# How to retrieve image from file path phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using following code to choose image from gallery and getting it's File path

```
  function getPhoto() 
{
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
}

     function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI)
    {
      // console.log(imageURI);

    var largeImage = document.getElementById('myImage');

       largeImage.style.display = 'block';
       largeImage.src = imageURI;

     window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imageURI, function(result) {
    // onSuccess code
    imageURI = 'file://' + result;
    console.log(imageURI);
```

Now I want to retrieve the image from the file path "imageURI" on different view page. How to do it?

Note: Got the solution. The same code

```
var largeImage = document.getElementById('demoimg');
            largeImage.style.display = 'block';
            console.log(imageURI);
            largeImage.src = imageURI;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want... You want to display the image inside a div container on another page than the actual one? Please describe what exactly you want

Comment: The problem has been solved.Thank you

Comment: It would be great to tell us, how you solved that problem!

Comment: You should answer your own question. This would help future users.